# Trix editor doesn't show up when used inside a @if condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, trix

In larave8 livewire I want to use the trix editor to create an bladeview on the livewire component InfoletterCrud is the following

```xml
<div class="container ml-auto mr-auto p-10 min-h-screen">
  <div class="page-title ">{{ $page_title }}</div>
  <div class="button-line flex flex-col">
    @if ($isEditMode)
      @if ($showMode)
        @include('livewire.show-infoletter')
      @else
        @include('livewire.create-infoletter')
      @endif
    @else
      <div>
        <button wire:click="create()" class="button-cancel text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded my-3">Ajouter une info-lettre</button>
      </div>
      @if (count($infoletters) > 0)
        <table class="w-full table-fixed admin-stripped-table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="w-full">
              <th class="w-1/12">Id</th>
              <th class="w-10/12">Titre</th>
              <th class="w-1/12">Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach ($infoletters as $infoletter)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $infoletter->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $infoletter->title }}</td>
                <td>
                  <div style="display:flex">
                    <button
                      wire:click="show({{ $infoletter->id }})"
                      class="fontawesome-icon">
                      <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Voir" class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-xs "></span>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      wire:click="edit({{ $infoletter->id }})"
                      class="fontawesome-icon">
                      <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Modifier" class="fa fa-edit fa-xs "></span>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      wire:click="$emit('openModal', 'livewire-modal', {{ json_encode(['type' => 'L\'infolettre', 'ident' => $infoletter->id]) }})"
                      class="fontawesome-icon">
                      <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Supprimer" class=" fa fa-trash fa-xs "></span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>,
      @else
        <p>Il n'y a aucune info-lettre</p>
      @endif
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

When I place the trix component with @livewire('trix') just above the @if (isEditMode)   test, it shows up. But it is not what I want because I am not in the Edit mode.

If I place it in the livewire.create-infoletter include, it doesn't show up.
Even when I place it just after the @if (isEditMode) test, it doesn't show up.

What is the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your component and how you're initializing Trix, so this is just a guess.  I'm assuming you're doing it with Alpinejs, and that Alpine has already made its DOM updates by the time the @if condition executes.  Try calling your initialization function using $nextTick - see here: https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick.

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by placing the js CDN and CSS CDN in the layout. It works.